# SQL Server table with Min Max instead of ID

Tags: sql-server

To save disk space and to easy the maintenaince, I changed table from (PeriodID, Value) to (MinPeriodID, MaxPeriodID, Value). All lines, which have same Value and are only 1 period apart, are being combined into 1 line.  For example, from 
(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(5,1)
it would change to (1,3,0), (5,1). What would be recommended, to query it as the same structure as before? Currently I transformed it to

```
SELECT P.PeriodID, T.Value
FROM Table T
JOIN Period P ON P.PeriodID BETWEEN T.MinPeriodID AND T.MaxPeriodID
```

,however, Period table is being scanned many times now.

**EDIT 1:**
This is example in dbfiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4fec0f1473c512fa38008c028af06606

My main goal is to have PeriodID back and query it as efficiently as before. This is is a screenshot from my actual query:

[image]

Period table is scanned a lot. Is there a way to replace this "between join"? Instead of that join, I want to cross join a row with sequence, which starts at T.MinPeriodID, ends at T.MaxPeriodID and has a step size of 1.

Comment: In the query posted there is no "many scans" of Period table. May be your original table had PK on id and now there is no index on (MinPeriodID, MaxPeriodID) include(value) so the query is slower

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't understand what it is you're looking for. Could you give us a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Give us your `period` table as DDL, and some data as DML (`CREATE TABLE...`) and then the result you want from the sample data. Sites such as [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/) can be very useful in this regard. There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look?

Comment: Could you please put the desired result from your data in the fiddle into the fiddle in the form of a comment? I still don't understand exactly what it is you require?

Comment: @Vérace, it is the desired result. I want to get it without using Period table, though.

Comment: You should update your question with actual execution plan. What you show is NOT table scans per query